# Adding a Linear Layout to a GridView Results in Each Element as A Complete Row

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add a LinearLayout to a GridView, and I'm having trouble.  Basically, I'm trying to make a set of icons with images beneath them.  (Like Launcher.app)

What I'm seeing is that when my GridView gets displayed, and it isn't broken into little icons.  Instead every icon displays in its own line.  Relevant files, and code below:

My Adaptor:

```
    @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LinearLayout llView;
            ImageView imageView;
            TextView textView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                LayoutInflater inflater = FolderSelectionActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                llView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.folder_view, null);
            } else {
                llView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
            }
            imageView = (ImageView) llView.findViewById(R.id.folder_image_view);
            textView = (TextView) llView.findViewById(R.id.folder_text_view);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(mDrive.getPreview(mFiles.get(position)));
            textView.setText(mFiles.get(position).getTitle());
            return llView;
```

My View's xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#FF0000FF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/folder_image_view"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="#FFFF0000"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/folder_text_view"
        android:background="#FF00FF00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, my Activity's Layout:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <GridView android:id="@+id/folder_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried all kinds of tweaks to my LinearLayout, but I can't seem to find anything that works.  Anyone know what to do here?

Edit:

imgur screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwy2I.jpg

Comment: The best practice to display any view, you must provice `dp` instead of `px`. Android recommended you to use `dp`.

Comment: Sure, but doesn't help.  :)

Comment: can you paste any output screenshot?

Comment: have you tried `android:columnWidth="<size>dp"` or `android:numColumns="auto_fit"` or `android:numColums="<num>"` options in `GridView`?

Comment: Also try `inflater.inflate(R.layout.folder_view, parent, false);`.

Comment: numColums seems to work.  Thanks, Chintan.  (If you add an answer, I'll flag it as correct).

Comment: Are you setting a listener on the grid view for when the individual items are clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you casting the inflated view or `convertView` to a `LinearLayout`? It's not necessary. Try after removing the cast statement `(LinearLayout)`. If that doesn't help, you can try constructing the `TextView` and `ImageView` separately and adding them to `ViewGroup parent` using `addView()`

Comment: I'm not sure any of this will work.  (1) The casting shouldn't make any difference.  (2) We're in the getView function for GridView's adaptor, so the view (when created) doesn't have a parent.  Unless I'm misunderstanding you.